# Can Proc SQL cause the value selected INTO a macro variable to be macro quoted?

Tags: sas

Consider this example where the selected value has special macro characters & and % the affect resolution. `%superq()` is used to mask the characters.

```
data have;
  id=1; s='A&B %now';

proc sql noprint;
  select s into :myvar from have where id=1;

%put &=myvar;
%put &myvar;

%let myvar = %superq(myvar);  /* macro quote the special symbols & and % */

%put &=myvar;

------------------- LOG -------------------
53   proc sql noprint;
54     select s into :myvar from have where id=1;
55
56   %put &=myvar;
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference B not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro NOW not resolved.
MYVAR=A&B %now
57   %put &myvar;
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference B not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro NOW not resolved.
A&B %now
58
59   %let myvar = %superq(myvar);  /* macro quote the special symbols & and % */
60
61   %put &=myvar;
MYVAR=A&B %now
```

Is there a `SELECT <expression> INTO :<symbol>` syntax where the value selected is forcibly macro quoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Add a %LET statement after the SELECT.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select s into :myvar from have where id=1;
%let myvar=%superq(myvar);
```

Or add actual quote characters.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select quote(trim(s),"'") into :myvar from have where id=1;
```